# Make an iOS app appear in Mobile Data, under 'use mobile data for'

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I know it's a silly question, can someone enlighten me how can I make the app appear in Settings > Mobile Data > USE MOBILE DATA FOR.

So that I can recreate the same experience (eg. Mail), if the user is not connected to Internet, it will prompt an alert that the mobile data is Turned Off

[image]

I can't seem to find any references. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That should appear automatically when you try using a mobile connection and the user has not allowed mobile data access through Settings > Mobile Data > USE MOBILE DATA FOR. Your app should appear there when it first uses mobile data.